# How to use Labels in static resource

Tags: visualforce, javascript, static-resources

I am using **static resource**, file default.js, where all javascript magic for visualforce page happens.
But, I come to the problem, when i want to use **custom labels**, there is an error

```
$Label is not defined
```

Syntax i am using is `$Label.Name_of_the_label`... even **Illuminated Cloud is showing me the name of the label is correct** and everything but label is not there and console showing me error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
//Add below 2 lines of code in the visualforce page
window.$Label = window.$Label || {};
$Label.customLabel= '{!($Label.myLabel)}'; // assigning the label to the JS variable.
var customLabelval =  $Label.customLabel;
Console.log(customLabelval);
```

Answer (score 1):

Expressions are not evaluated in a Static Resource. They are used verbatim. The standard way to handle this is to have a global variable in your main Visualforce page that handles this:

```
var labels = { ABC: "{!JSENCODE($Label.ABC)}", XYZ: "{!JSENCODE($Label.XYZ)}" };

...

var someString = labels.ABC;
```